# iPhone contacts bar with letters doesn't work for letters D-Y?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I have this very strange issue with my iPhone 4's (iOS 5.0.1 9A405) Contacts app.

As you know, there is this "bar" on the right which allows you to touch a letter and have the table directly "jump" to that letter:

[image]

On my iPhone, the bar only works for letters A, B, C, and Z. Not the letters in between. If I touch any of the letters D-Y, it jumps to C. Huh? Note that searching for a contact starting with letters D-Y and/or scrolling to it manually works fine.

While investigating for the possible cause of this weird behavior, I also found out that there's a section `#` between the letters C and D, which I suspect might be causing the problem. Why is it there? All contacts in that section start with C and should thus be in the `C` section. Here are two screenshots of the misplaced `#` section:

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to iOS 5.1 to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @RandolphWest: no, because my iPhone is jailbroken and thus I need to stay on 5.0.1 (there is no untethered jailbreak for iOS 5.1 yet).

Comment: I would suggest that running on an older, and unsupported, OS, is going to make answering your question difficult, especially if this is a known problem that has been repaired in iOS 5.1 (I don't know whether or not this is true, but it's a possibility).

Comment: @RandolphWest: I do realize that ideally I would update. However, I know many people for whom this works just fine, and they are also on iOS 5.0.1, so I don't think this is a known issue.

Comment: @RandolphWest: I'm now on 5.1.1 (latest), and the issue is still there... I've tried doing a full restore too, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Since you have a backup, what happens when you do a clean setup, with no restore?

Comment: @RandolphWest: I now fixed the problem as mentioned below, but thanks for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this by removing/renaming all the contacts in the misplaced '#' section.

No idea why it happened in the first place...

Comment: Interesting find. I've voted this up.